# Update progressbar's value from another thread?

Tags: c#, delegates, progress-bar, backgroundworker, multithreading

My form creates a backgroundworker that every 6 secs checks something. Result is 1-100 and I want to display this.

But if i do it straight forward i get som cross-thread errors so I after some research delegates is the way to do it.

ive created inside the Form1 class:

```
public delegate void SetProgressbarValueDelegate(int val);
```

but how do i "connect it" to actually update the progressbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your are using WinForms, The `BackgroundWorker` class raises a [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event which will automatically be marshalled back onto your UI thread. You should make updates to your User Interface within your handler for this event.

There are some simple examples of how to use `BackgroundWorker` within the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx).

Comment: Okey, it initially works. but if i have a value, lets stay 99 and want it to be the new value of the progressbar, how can i send it? im doing (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(99); inside worker_DoWork but really i want to transmit data, not just number (for use with other controls)

Comment: Sorry I have accidentally made a downvote on this one although my intention was to upvote. And I cannot change it until question is edited. Sorry, sorry! But please edit and I will undo my stupid deeds.